# How to check integrity of system if Wubi not shut down properly

Tags: wubi, recovery-mode, fsck

For argument's sake, let's say that my Ubuntu installation of 14.04 (32-bit) using Wubi was not shut down properly, either due to it hanging or forcibly being shut down by a critically low battery.  Also, for argument's sake, I am able to restart wubi without any problem.  Does this mean that the integrity of the system (particularly, root.disk) has not been compromised?  How would I go about checking this? Would running fsck in recovery mode suffice, or would I need to do something more?

Comment: What do you mean with "Wubi not shut down properly"? Wubi is an installation program, nothing that will "shut down".

Comment: @the_Seppi - What I mean is the wubi installation of Ubuntu.  If you need specific version numbers, it is Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run file system integrity checks on the host partition (`NTFS`) as well as on the `root.disk` (`ext3/4`). You should always run it in this order, because the `root.disk` is also a file and if it is corrupt, trying to `fsck` it won't help and may in fact damage it further.**

So, when I am concerned due to some event, for example a hardware crash that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> couldn't recover and a hard shutdown was required,... then I would:

1. Boot Windows and select the host *drive*, Tools, Repair. If it's
   `C:` then you'll have to reboot and let Windows boot to get `chkdsk`
   to run.
2. Boot from a *Live USB/DVD* and `fsck` the `root.disk`:

   `fsck -fvy /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk`

You could probably `fsck` it in recovery mode also, but usually doing it from a live CD is easiest.

** I am very convinced of this having worked with many people who've lost their Wubi installs, and it seems that running `fsck` first (usually via `boot-repair`) on a corrupted `NTFS` filesystem can damage the `root.disk` beyond repair.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, bcbc!  It seems I have a horse shoe up my backside because I ran fsck first without considering the NTFS.  Note that no errors were detected with fsck (which I ran in recovery mode).  I have since checked the NTFS using chkdsk.  No errors were detected for either drive C: nor drive D:.  I think what saved me was the fact that I have root.disk installed on the D: drive under Windows 7, while NTFS does its journaling on the C: drive.  That, and the fact that the laptop had been left idle for a couple of hours before the battery ran flat....

Comment: Check your Power settings - maybe it's set to shutdown on a critically low battery. Or maybe it's the horseshoe. Either way, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The "integrity" of an installation is ambiguous.

To clarify, I assume you mean "Is the filesystem in a clean state?"  This is hard to test when your installation is Wubi - you can't easily identify the Wubi file system from a Live environment, for example, as the Wubi file system is actually just stored on Windows itself, as a file container, and not really a true partition.

Given that, there's no way to really run a `fsck` in a sane and easy way on the Wubi installation.  It also is not possible to glean whether the filesystem is clean or not based on whether the system boots - for example, on my previous system, my OS booted, but then had input/output errors due to bad sectors on the hard drive.  The system said the filesystem was "clean" but had a bad sector count.  That in and of itself does not, therefore, determine whether the "integrity" of a system is compromised.

You need to be more clear on what you mean by "integrity" in context of your question.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I assumed as much. When I say integrity of the system, I do mean file system, and issues that result in the corruption thereof....